# java error, can not find symbol

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I am trying to build a chess board, but I keep getting an error that I can not seem to fix.

I have tried to find what it could be, but I am just lost.

my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class chess extends JFrame {
int column_want, column_curr, column_diff;
int row_want, row_curr, row_diff;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to java");
        board frame = new boardLayout();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setTitle("chess Board");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center of frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
public void boardLayout() {
    JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,5,1,1)); // gridLayout (row, column, hgap, vgap)
    add(board, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}


}
```

it claims to be on line 12, but I do not know why there might be an error there.

line 12:

```
    board frame = new boardLayout();
```

Comment: `new` is for object contruction - not for calling functions (especially with `void` return type..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a type `board`, which is neither in the imports, nor in the file. Then you try to create an instance of a class `boardLayout`, which is unknown just as the type was.

`public void boardLayout()` is a method declaration, it won't work as an constructor, unless it has the same name as the class it belongs to, and you will remove the return type `void`. Like `public chess()`.

A constructor does have its return type declared, as it is known, that it returns the object it instantiates. So `new chess()` will return a new object of a type `chess`.

Comment: I am trying to implement your suggestions, but I must not be understanding them. I removed `void` from `public void boardLayout`, I tried renaming the constructor to `chess`, but I am still finding the same error on the same line.
I moved `JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,5,1,1));` up to the variable declare block, but it changed nothing but the line the error was on. @EddyG

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `new JPanel()` being within the constructor. Did you  modify the types to be correct, like `chess frame = new chess()`?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up syntax element. You only need to use the `new` keyword when creating new objects. When calling methods, no need to use "new".

Hint on naming: a method name should contain a verb, so `createBoard` would be more "java style".